# Java: Sending text to windows on Linux

Tags: java, linux, automation

I am running some automation on Linux (over docker), specifically automating some Firefox actions.

At one stage I need to send text to an "Upload file" text box.

[image: This specific example is from windows, but the test runs on Linux]

This specific example is from windows, but the test runs on Linux.

I found no clue how can I achieve that.

Can you assist please?

Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, you can generate key press events with the Robot class. This code presses the A key:

```
    Robot robot = new Robot(); 
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
```

There's a complete example at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/robot-class-java-awt/ and you can find many more by searching on the internet for "Java robot automation" or similar search terms

Comment: The Java Robot class works on Linux. I suggested using it because you tagged the question with Java.  If you prefer to use something other than the Java programming language, include it in the question.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to work with Java. If you say Robot is good also for Linux, I will defiently check it. Thanks!!

Comment: If you're interested to learn *how* it works on Linux, it uses the XTEST extension of the X11 window system https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/xextproto/xtest.html